# How to limit google place api search to any specific city in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to perform a search location using Android Google Places API and `AutoCompleteTextView` and I need to restrict the search prediction to any specific city.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: http://codetheory.in/google-place-api-autocomplete-service-in-android-application/

Comment: Already using the same link @Mrinmoy :( this is not the solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33343155/5722385

Comment: Not country, I am asking for city or state.

Comment: I already told you i do not want filter according to country, I need filter for city or state.